# How to create the deployproj file from the command line

Tags: delphi

the `deployproj` is a temporary file that is generated from the dproj file every time we deploy the project from the delphi ide. But it's not the case from the command line. I build and deploy my project like this :

```
MSBuild %ProjectDir%\MyApp.dproj /p:Config=Release /p:Platform=Android /t:Build;Deploy
```

but if the `deployproj` not exist (or is not updated), then this command will failed :( Is their any way to generate the `deployproj` from the command line ?

Comment: From this: http://blog.blong.com/2017/10/delphi-buildinstall-to-android-from.html
It looks like you need to do at least *one* deployment with the IDE, or create one manually. I guess you could create a blank project and do a deployment to see the minimum that is required?

Comment: @DaveNottage. thanks that is the problem the deployproj is created only from the ide onle :(